# iOS: CFRunLoopRun() function confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cfrunloop

I've read about `CFRunLoop` but still a bit confused about it. I came a cross a piece of code that I'd like to clarify for myself:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:url]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

CFRunLoopRun();
```

So, assuming this is all being called on the main thread, will it block the main thread? Or will it spawn a new thread through the `CFRunLoopRun()` function call?

Thanks!

Comment: This is normally run when the request is going on in a background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is called from the main thread, there isn't really any reason to call `CFRunLoopRun`, because the default run loop should already be running.

The way you're using `NSURLConnection` will not block the calling thread. It *may* spawn additional threads internally, but you don't really have to care about that. `initWithRequest:delegate:` will return pretty much immediately and your delegate methods will be called later (when a response is received, data is loaded, etc.).

Comment: Interesting. So within the delegate's connectionDidFinishLoading I see the following call:

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());

will that cause any issues based on your answer? Will it try to stop the default run loop?

Comment: I would guess that the code you're looking at is designed to run on a secondary thread. From my understanding of how `CFRunLoopRun` works, `CFRunLoopStop` should only stop the nested run loop that was created by `CFRunLoopRun`, but I could be wrong. On the main thread, neither of these things make a lot of sense.

Comment: That's what I thought, but needed to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

There is actually a case where it makes sense. While creating a recursive run loop (that's what will happen when you execute that line):

> It is possible to run a run loop recursively. In other words, you can
>   call CFRunLoopRun, CFRunLoopRunInMode, or any of the NSRunLoop methods
>   for starting the run loop from within the handler routine of an input
>   source or timer. When doing so, you can use any mode you want to run
>   the nested run loop, including the mode in use by the outer run loop.

So the point is to do something like this:

```
- (NSMutableData *)serverRequest
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:url]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    CFRunLoopRun();
    return _returnDataFromServer;
}
```

So the method `serverRequest` won't exit, until you actually stop the RunLoop:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [_connectionData appendData:data];

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

I wouldn't do this, it's preferable to pass this piece of work to a working thread.There are others ways to achieve the same and not use Run Loop.